# Flash object doesn't work when dynamically added to the DOM in IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, flash, internet-explorer, object

I am doing an ajax request with jQuery that returns some html and then I am inserting that html into the DOM. The HTML is as follows:

```
    <div class="entry-details">
            <div class="brightcove-player-wrap">
        <!-- Start of Brightcove Player -->
            <div style="display:none">
            </div>
            <!--
            By use of this code snippet, I agree to the Brightcove Publisher T and C
            found at https://accounts.brightcove.com/en/terms-and-conditions/.
            -->
            <script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript" src="http://admin.brightcove.com/js/BrightcoveExperiences.js"></script>
            <object id="myExperience4733627893001" class="BrightcoveExperience">
              <param name="bgcolor" value="#FFFFFF" />
              <param name="width" value="1130" />
              <param name="height" value="500" />
              <param name="playerID" value="4732606104001" />
              <param name="playerKey" value="AQ~~,AAABAzMvv-k~,LozjqgbLEy1mFJ0QaG0FQ_ctTc2aT68o" />
              <param name="isVid" value="true" />
              <param name="isUI" value="true" />
              <param name="dynamicStreaming" value="true" />

              <param name="@videoPlayer" value="4733627893001" />
            </object>
            <!--
            This script tag will cause the Brightcove Players defined above it to be created as soon
            as the line is read by the browser. If you wish to have the player instantiated only after
            the rest of the HTML is processed and the page load is complete, remove the line.
            -->
            <script type="text/javascript">brightcove.createExperiences();</script>
            <!-- End of Brightcove Player -->
        </div>
        <div class="entry-like">
        <a href="" data-entry-id="291" class="btn btn-lime">Like <i class="icon-thumbs-up"></i></a>
    </div>
    <div class="entry-intro">
        <span>Submitted by:</span> Geoff Meierhans<br>
                <span>Location:</span> United Kingdom<br>
        <span>Likes:</span> 0    </div>

    <br>
    <div class="question-1">
        <h4>What message would you like to give to lung cancer patients?</h4>
        <p>This is my message</p>
    </div>

    <br>
    <div class="request-removal">
        <a href="http://local.tagrisso.com/request_removal/291" class="btn btn-mulberry">Request Removal <i class="icon-remove icon-white"></i></a>
    </div>
</div>
```

This works fine in chrome but not in any version of IE. If the object is already on the page when the page loads it works fine and the video plays but when I insert it dynamically with jQuery the video doesn't appear in IE.

```
Could not complete the operation due to error 80020101
```

Here is the jQuery I am using with version 1.9.1 of jQuery:

```
var request = $.ajax({
    url: "user/get_message",
    method: "POST",
    data: { id : entryId },
    dataType: "html",
    cache: false
});

request.done(function(html) {
    $('#entry-info').html(html);
});
```

Anyone know why this is happening and what the fix might be?

**UPDATE**

I managed to fix it in IE8 and upwards by including the brightcove js file on page load rather than dynamically. So move the following line from the ajax response into the main DOM:

```
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript" src="http://admin.brightcove.com/js/BrightcoveExperiences.js"></script>
```

It still doesn't work in IE7 though, anyone know why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I had to create a blank page with just the video on and then just dynamically add an iframe that displays that instead.